# need help in VSCODE debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm a VSCODE first-time user. I tried to run debug on a simple python file and was not successful. I got 2 strange results:

1. the debug tool bar showed and disappeared instantly
2. no local variables was shown in VARIABLE section

Please see the screenshot.
Anyone could give me a hint anything was missing in what I did?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need the [python vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to debug a python file. When you press F5 to start debugging, a menu will ask you what you are trying to debug. Click on Python File. The python extension creates a launch.json file for you and starts the debugger.

I noticed the Run and Debug tab is in your screenshot. Click that tab above where the variables would be shown and it should ask you to create the launch.json file in order to debug the file.

Read more on debugging and launch configurations for python here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used vscode for Linux and displayed remotely to Windows. As you can see in the second picture, I did install python vscode extension. and when I was prompted to create the launch.json file, I Click on Python File, as you can see it displayed "Python: Current File"  next to Run and Debug. It just didn't work. then, I tried the same on Windows native installation, and it worked properly. Not sure why it showed this behavior.